# FireFox isn't working after updating FoxyProxy plugin

Tags: macos, firefox

I have FireFox 3.6 installed in my OS X 10.6 and I have FoxyProxy plugin installed.
An update for FoxyProxy was available so I updated it.
After updating, FireFox isn't launching and it is disappears immediately.

Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To launch Firefox in Safe Mode on OS X, open `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal` and enter the following:

```
open -a Firefox --args -safe-mode
```

Try disabling or uninstalling the plugin to see if it works again.

---

You can also try to get information from the system logs. Open `/Applications/Utilities/Console` to see them. You can search for "Firefox" or "firefox-bin" to see messages related to Firefox.

Are there logs related to Firefox in *Files » ~/Library/Logs » CrashReporter*? Does their time stamp conform with the recent crashes?

---

What (error message) output do you see when you open Firefox by launching `Terminal` and entering the following:

`/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin`

(Assuming Firefox is located in `/Applications/`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the problem itself, but you should be able to launch Firefox to remove/downgrade FoxyProxy in safe mode. Go to the Mozilla Firefox program group in your start menu, there should be a shortcut to run Firefox in Safe Mode. If not, simply create a shortcut to Firefox and change the target so that it contains the argument `-safe-mode`.